# Errors happended while writing metric to influxDB

Tags: jmeter

I create a test.jmx as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.2.1">
  <hashTree>
   <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
  <stringProp name="TestPlan.comments"></stringProp>
  <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
  <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">true</boolProp>
  <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
  <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
    <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
  </elementProp>
  <stringProp name="TestPlan.user_define_classpath"></stringProp>
</TestPlan>
<hashTree>
  <BackendListener guiclass="BackendListenerGui" testclass="BackendListener" enabled="true">
    <elementProp name="arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" enabled="true">
      <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
        <elementProp name="influxdbMetricsSender" elementType="Argument">
          <stringProp name="Argument.name">influxdbMetricsSender</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.value">org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.influxdb.HttpMetricsSender</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <elementProp name="influxdbUrl" elementType="Argument">
          <stringProp name="Argument.name">influxdbUrl</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.value">http://tsdb-test.intra.yiran.com:8086/write?db=opencloud_monitor;u=opencloud_monitor_rw;p=ZmFiM2IyMDgxNWQ5NGY4</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <elementProp name="application" elementType="Argument">
          <stringProp name="Argument.name">application</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.value">VIP_TestPlan_1</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <elementProp name="measurement" elementType="Argument">
          <stringProp name="Argument.name">measurement</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.value">jmeter</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <elementProp name="summaryOnly" elementType="Argument">
          <stringProp name="Argument.name">summaryOnly</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.value">false</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <elementProp name="samplersRegex" elementType="Argument">
          <stringProp name="Argument.name">samplersRegex</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.value">.*</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <elementProp name="percentiles" elementType="Argument">
          <stringProp name="Argument.name">percentiles</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.value">90;95;99</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <elementProp name="testTitle" elementType="Argument">
          <stringProp name="Argument.name">testTitle</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.value">Test name</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
        <elementProp name="eventTags" elementType="Argument">
          <stringProp name="Argument.name">eventTags</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.value"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
        </elementProp>
      </collectionProp>
    </elementProp>
    <stringProp name="classname">org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.influxdb.InfluxdbBackendListenerClient</stringProp>
  </BackendListener>
  <hashTree/>
  <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Example Thread Group" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">10</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">0</stringProp>
    <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" enabled="true">
      <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
      <intProp name="LoopController.loops">-1</intProp>
    </elementProp>
    <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">true</boolProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">10</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay">0</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
    <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
  </ThreadGroup>
  <hashTree>
    <HTTPSamplerProxy guiclass="HttpTestSampleGui" testclass="HTTPSamplerProxy" enabled="true">
      <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="HTTPArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
      </elementProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.domain">www.csdn.net</stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.port">19252</stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.protocol">http</stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.contentEncoding"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.path">/</stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.method">GET</stringProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.follow_redirects">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.auto_redirects">true</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.use_keepalive">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="HTTPSampler.DO_MULTIPART_POST">false</boolProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.embedded_url_re"></stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.connect_timeout">5000</stringProp>
      <stringProp name="HTTPSampler.response_timeout"></stringProp>
    </HTTPSamplerProxy>
    <hashTree/>
  </hashTree>
  <ResultCollector guiclass="SummaryReport" testclass="ResultCollector" enabled="true">
    <boolProp name="ResultCollector.error_logging">false</boolProp>
    <objProp>
      <name>saveConfig</name>
      <value class="SampleSaveConfiguration">
        <time>true</time>
        <latency>true</latency>
        <timestamp>true</timestamp>
        <success>true</success>
        <label>true</label>
        <code>true</code>
        <message>true</message>
        <threadName>true</threadName>
        <dataType>true</dataType>
        <encoding>false</encoding>
        <assertions>true</assertions>
        <subresults>true</subresults>
        <responseData>false</responseData>
        <samplerData>false</samplerData>
        <xml>false</xml>
        <fieldNames>true</fieldNames>
        <responseHeaders>false</responseHeaders>
        <requestHeaders>false</requestHeaders>
        <responseDataOnError>false</responseDataOnError>
        <saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>true</saveAssertionResultsFailureMessage>
        <assertionsResultsToSave>0</assertionsResultsToSave>
        <bytes>true</bytes>
        <sentBytes>true</sentBytes>
        <url>true</url>
        <threadCounts>true</threadCounts>
        <idleTime>true</idleTime>
        <connectTime>true</connectTime>
      </value>
    </objProp>
    <stringProp name="filename"></stringProp>
    </ResultCollector>
    <hashTree/>
  </hashTree>
</hashTree>
```

no errors recorded in jmeter.log, but there are only "startedT" datas:

```
{
"time": "2020-01-16T13:11:42.507Z",
"application": "VIP_TestPlan_1",
"avg": null,
"count": null,
"countError": null,
"endedT": 0,
"hit": null,
"max": null,
"maxAT": 0,
"meanAT": 0,
"min": null,
"minAT": 0,
"pct90.0": null,
"pct95.0": null,
"pct99.0": null,
"rb": null,
"sb": null,
"startedT": 0,
"statut": null,
 "transaction": "internal"
},
{
  "time": "2020-01-16T13:11:47.507Z",
"application": "VIP_TestPlan_1",
"avg": null,
"count": null,
"countError": null,
"endedT": 0,
"hit": null,
"max": null,
"maxAT": 0,
"meanAT": 0,
"min": null,
"minAT": 0,
"pct90.0": null,
"pct95.0": null,
"pct99.0": null,
"rb": null,
"sb": null,
"startedT": 500,
"statut": null,
"transaction": "internal"
},
```

[image]

summary report: 
summary +  20166 in 00:00:18 = 1115.6/s Avg:   165 Min:     0 Max:  5300 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 500 Started: 500 Finished: 0
summary +  61507 in 00:00:30 = 2050.2/s Avg:   191 Min:     0 Max:  4499 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 500 Started: 500 Finished: 0
summary =  81673 in 00:00:48 = 1698.8/s Avg:   185 Min:     0 Max:  5300 Err:     0 (0.00%)
summary +   4246 in 00:00:15 =  280.9/s Avg:  1570 Min:     0 Max: 18600 Err:     7 (0.16%) Active: 0 Started: 500 Finished: 500
summary =  85919 in 00:01:03 = 1359.6/s Avg:   253 Min:     0 Max: 18600 Err:     7 (0.01%)
anything wrong with my jmx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all don't expose your credentials to public
2. Second, your .jmx test plan is missing `</jmeterTestPlan>` closing tag
3. Your [Backend Listener configuration looks good](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html), I fail to see why the metrics are not stored, try [increasing JMeter log level verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for the Backend Listener, it can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.backend.influxdb" level="debug"/>
   ```

   Once done check your *jmeter.log* file, it should contain lines like:

   ```
   HttpMetricsSender: Success, number of metrics written: x
   ...
   InfluxdbBackendListenerClient: Sending last metrics
   ```

   [image]

Assuming everything goes well you should see the data in the InfluxDB:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer @Dmitri T, i found the cause of this problem, that this jmx works in my local computer, while could not write complete data into influxDB in pod(excute jmx in non-ui mode), everything went well after i changed the structure of hashtree in jmx, the backendlistner should in the subtree of threadgrouptree. But the reason of problem in the formal situation is still unknown